# How to print or debug array or object in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, log, debug

I am working on Magento 2.

```
if ($this->getRequest()->isAjax()) {
    $layout =  $this->_layout;
}
```

How can I print or debug value of `$layout` in above code ??

Comment: echo $data = print_r($layout, TRUE);

Answer (score 3):

you can print **$layout** in log file like in below code and see results in **var/log/debug.log** file

```
class Example{
protected $_logger;
public function __construct(
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger, //log injection
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_logger = $logger;
    parent::__construct($data);
}
public function someExampleMethod() {
    /*
    some logic of method
    */
    //accessing to logger instance and calling log method
    $this->_logger->log('some text or variable');
    /// for array use this
   // $this->_logger->log(100,print_r($layout,true));
}
```

}

you can also print it like that to see result

```
print_r($layout);exit;
```

Answer (score 3):

On top of what Ashar Riaz said, you can also use the `debug` method from `\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface` :

```
$this->_logger->debug(var_export($layout, true));
```

IIRC, the values will be logged under `var/log/debug.log`

Answer (score 1):

You can print any object using debug function. Review below link

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/DataObject.php#L461-L489

for print layout object you can use

> $layout->debug()

Answer (score 0):

Hope, it will be helpful.

```
print_r($layout);
```

Comment: If you try print_r wirh magento objects, you run out of memory

Answer (score 0):

`var_dump()` is a good way too, you could use `<pre>` to format the output.

```
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($layout);
echo "</pre>";
exit;
```